# Cannot find symbol class onClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development. Here's the problem i ran into.
  I'm using Android Studio.
  I looked up on many sites, they said to import the related class. Having done
  that, the problem remains.
  Any help is appreciated.

Can anyone please help me with this, i have been searching for a while now for the solution.

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.veeresh.myapplication;
//import statements
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(
                //error: cannot find symbol class onClickListener
                new Button.onClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
                        text1.setText("Veeresh Here");
                    }
                }
                );
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Error:(24, 27) error: cannot find symbol class onClickListener
>              Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>              Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Use new View.OnClickListener() instead of Button.OnClickListener

Comment: same error : Error:(24, 21) error: cannot find symbol class onClickListener

Comment: Error:(24, 21) error: cannot find symbol class onClickListener

Comment: Try changing `Button.onClickListener()` to `OnClickListener()` and add `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `new View.OnClickListener()` instead of `new Button.onClickListener()`

`OnClickListener` with a capital O.

Comment: done that but same error: Error:(24, 21) error: cannot find symbol class onClickListener

Comment: Try capital O in OnClickListener and also don't forget to import View in your java file by writing -->     import android.view.View;

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                text1.setText("Veeresh Here");
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code with the below code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text1.setText("Veeresh Here");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both  `Button.OnClickListener()` and `View.OnClickListener()` works fine it is just the capital **O** that you are missing.